# Complex redirect with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yourls

How I can redirect

- **o**site.com
- en.**o**site.com
- ru.**o**site.com/product/1

and other different subdomains respectively to

- so.kr/index.php?url=**site.com**
- so.kr/index.php?url=**en.site.com**
- so.kr/index.php?url=**ru.site.com/product/1**

in Apache?
This is need for convenient links shortening of site.com.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand it, but it work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.osite\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://%1.site.ru$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```